# get current location android

Tags: android, android-location

I have a problem with getting current location because, I have in my **MainActivity** the listener:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATE,
                MINIMUM_DISTANCECHANGE_FOR_UPDATE,
                new MyLocationListener()
        );
```

And I have a second activity where I would, when i click on button, calculate distance from my location and gps coordinate that I will pass with `distanceTo` and return true if the distance is beetween 0 and 200.
So I have a function in **SecondActivity**

```
private boolean checkCoordinate(String gps) {
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(App.getContext().LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            return false;
        }

        Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        double currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();
        double currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();

        Location loc1 = new Location("");
        loc1.setLatitude(currentLatitude);
        loc1.setLongitude(currentLongitude);



        String[] sep = gps.split(",");
        double latitude = Double.parseDouble(sep[0]);
        double longitude = Double.parseDouble(sep[1]);



        Location loc2 = new Location("");
        loc2.setLatitude(latitude);
        loc2.setLongitude(longitude);

        float distanceInMeters = loc1.distanceTo(loc2);
        if(distanceInMeters < 200){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

But the problem is that someTimes and maybe when I don't change my location the function:

```
Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

return null, and I don't understand how know my current location because I have already set requestLocationUpdates.
so I how can know my current location?

Answer (score 1):

`getLastKnownLocation` will return `null` if GPS based location is disabled in system or there was no GPS fix since system startup. If you want to ensure there is a location you can use the `requestSingleUpdate`-method, it will not return until there is a location available.

It might also be a good idea to not use the APIs based on specific provider name if it's not important to use a specific provider (usually it is not important how you got the location). The API contains methods that take a `Criteria`-object instead of a provider name and you can define very precisely what accuracy level etc. you want.

Comment: Yes I've realized that the problem is not startup GPS provider, and for now I've "temporarily solved" with `if(location == null){ location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER); }` . But I don't know if a bad practice or if could do a problem, but seems work even the location is less accuracy

Comment: although this occurs far less often, network location might be missing as well.

Comment: Ok thankyou, so I have use `requestSingleUpdate` instead `requestLocationUpdates` or use `requestSingleUpdate` in My function `checkCoordinate`

Comment: If I understand you right, you want to know if the user moved a certain distance in a rather short time. If that's the case, the easiest way would be to use `requestLocationUpdates()` with the minimum distance set to your desired distance (200 in your example). If you don't get a second location from your listener, the user is still at the same location

Comment: no, i would like know the current position, even if it does not perform movements, but it work, the problem is (i believe) that GPS provider sometimes is not startup, or in that moment, gps is not available because I'm testing form my chair in office! :)  and the position is undefined.